# Google app script adding a function to new columns

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, multiple-columns

First time time writting, long time reading.
I have a google sheet that is always being updated with three columns at the end.
I want to write a script that will add the three colums at the end and then add a function to each new columns and pull the fuction/formula down.
This is what I have so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

```
 function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var column = sh.insertColumnsAfter(1, 3);
  var cell = ss.getRange("");
  cell.setFormula();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how to add formulas and copy them down.

**Code.gs**

```
function addColumns() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.insertColumnsAfter(1,3)
    let formulas = [["=A1","=A1+A2","=A1+A2+A3"]];
    let source = sheet.getRange(1,2,1,3)
    source.setFormulas(formulas);
    let destination = sheet.getRange(2,2,10,3); // B2:D11
    source.copyTo(destination);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [Sheet.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [Range.setFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasformulas)
- [Range.copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)

Comment: Right on thank you so much for your reply to my issue. Woudl there be much more if i was to add a function =Array in place of the formula?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "=Array"